# react How do I check if string is empty

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have a component in React that displays time from a JSON data file:

```
<div>
  <div>
    {startTime && (
      <div className={style.startTime}>
        {moment(stop?.on?.time).format("HH:mm:ss")}
      </div>
    )}
    {endTime && (
      <div className={style.endTime}>
        {moment(stop?.off?.time).format("HH:mm:ss")}
      </div>
    )}
  </div>

</div>;
```

This works fine that it displays the time from the file. However, now I am trying to write a ternary that will hide the time if there is no data in the JSON file.

```
<div>
  <div>
    {startTime === true
      ? startTime && <div>{moment(stop?.on?.time).format("HH:mm:ss")}</div>
      : null}

    {endTime === true
      ? endTime && <div>{moment(stop?.off?.time).format("HH:mm:ss")}</div>
      : null}
  </div>
</div>;
```

This doesn't work. If the condition is `=== true` both return nothing. If I set it to `!==`, it returns both values.

How do I get it to show or hide the value if the JSON object exists and has data?

Answer (score 2):

## String will never be equal to true

The string can be parsed to a boolean by adding `!!` at the front. If the string is empty this value will be `false` and if it has some text inside it will be `true`.

```
<div>
  <div>
    {!!startTime
      ? startTime && <div>{moment(stop?.on?.time).format("HH:mm:ss")}</div>
      : null}

    {!!endTime
      ? endTime && <div>{moment(stop?.off?.time).format("HH:mm:ss")}</div>
      : null}
  </div>
</div>;
```